# Abstracting the process of finding the index of the maximum in Python

Tags: python, search, higher-order-functions

Suppose I want to find the index of the maximal value of a given sequence. In Matlab, this is:

```
[value, index] = max(x)
```

In Python, I would abstract the following pattern:

```
def find_best_element_index(elements, is_better):
    best_so_far = elements[0]
    best_so_far_index = 0
    for (index, element) in enumerate(elements):
        if is_better(element, best_so_far):
            best_so_far = element
            best_so_far_index = index
    return best_so_far_index
```

Which I could use in the following way:

```
import operator
assert find_best_element_index([6, 3, 9, 8, 0, 9, 7, 9, 7, 8], operator.gt) == 2
```

But I wonder if there is a more pythonic way to go when I just want to find the index of the "best" item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I just want to find the index of the "best" item.

This can be written very shortly and readably using `enumerate`, `first class functions` and `list indexing`.

```
def index_of_max_value(items):
    return max(enumerate(items), key = lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

**Explanation:**

1. I create a list that contains the numbers and their indexes, the index is first, the number second.

```
>>> list(enumerate([4,7,4,8]))
[(0, 4), (1, 7), (2, 4), (3, 8)]
```

2. I ask the item that has the biggest value when a function I decide is applied to it, I do so by passing the function as the key argument, when functions are passed around like this they are `first class citizens`

```
>>> max(["rg","gu","sd"], key = lambda s: sum(map(ord,s)))
'gu'
```

For example in the above I asked which of the strings had the most ASCII value.

```
key = lambda x: x[1]
```

Means that I want the pair (index,number) that has the biggest 'second' item (remember zero indexing).

3. `[n]` gives you the n-th item of a list, I ask the '0-th' (first) item that is the index.

I hope that you like my alternative shorter solution, if you have any doubts, fell free to ask.

Comment: Great one-liner! I didn't know that I could provide an optional key argument to `max`. In this way, I can use `max` to calculate the index of the **min** value too! ;)

Comment: BTW, can you confirm that the required size is constant, i.e., that `max` does not construct the whole list of couples?

Comment: @Aristide `enumerate` yields an `iterator`, that is like a `promise` or a `lazy list`, it is consumed value after value, so the space requirement are `O(1)`, that is only two items in memory at any given time: the current max and the item to compare.

Comment: Sorry, my question was too broad, I have edited it in order to suppress the second part, since your answer is a perfect fit for the first one. I'll ask the second question separately. Thanks for your explanations!

Comment: @Aristide you are welcome!